# Почему происходит ошибка при отображение данных СoreData в TableView?

Tags: ios, swift

Почему происходит ошибка при отображение данных `СoreData` в *TableView*?

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
2017-12-23 16:38:29.975474+0200 tableViewWithDifferentEntities[63437:4211251] [error] error: NSFetchedResultsController: no section at index 1 in sections list
CoreData: error: NSFetchedResultsController: no section at index 1 in sections list
2017-12-23 16:38:29.986 tableViewWithDifferentEntities[63437:4211251] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'no section at index 1'
```

Я ж создаю 2 раздела(секции ) в методе `numberOfSections`, а потом в методах `numberOfRowsInSection` и `cellForRowAt`, в зависимости от индекса раздела ввожу данные. А в логе пишется, что нет индекса с номером 1 , почему ?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableView: UIViewController,  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{



    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var fetchedResultsController = CoreDataManager.instance.fetchedResultsController("Customer", keyForSort: "name")

    var fetchedResultsController2 = CoreDataManager.instance.fetchedResultsController("Seller", keyForSort: "name_seller")

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTableView.delegate=self
        myTableView.dataSource=self

        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        fetchedResultsController2.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print(error)

        }
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController2.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print(error)

        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections
            return sections![0].numberOfObjects
        }
        else {
            let sections = fetchedResultsController2.sections
            return sections![0].numberOfObjects
        }


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "0", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
            let customer = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! Customer
            cell.textLabel?.text = customer.name
            return (cell)

        } else  {
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "1", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell2

            let seller = fetchedResultsController2.object(at: indexPath) as! Seller
            cell2.textLabel?.text = seller.name_seller
            return (cell2)
        }
    }



    @IBAction func AddCustomer(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "customersToCustomer", sender: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func AddSeller(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "sellersToSeller", sender: nil)
    }



    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

        myTableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        let section = controller == fetchedResultsController ? 0 : 1
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            myTableView.insertRows(at: [[section, newIndexPath!.row]], with: .automatic)
        case .update:
            if section == 0 {
                let customer = controller.object(at: indexPath!) as! Customer
                let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: [0, indexPath!.row])
                cell!.textLabel?.text = customer.name
            } else {
                let seller = controller.object(at: indexPath!) as! Seller
                let cell2 = myTableView.cellForRow(at: [1, indexPath!.row])
                cell2!.textLabel?.text = seller.name_seller
            }
        case .delete:
            myTableView.deleteRows(at: [[section, (indexPath?.row)!]], with: .automatic)
        default: break
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {

        myTableView.endUpdates()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            let result = fetchedResultsController.sections
            return result![0].numberOfObjects
        }
        else {
            let result = fetchedResultsController2.sections
            return result![0].numberOfObjects
        }    
    }
```

Ошибку дает не UITableView а CoreData.